# How to find the dict which has more number of filled values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, optimization

I have two `Dict`s

```
a = {'A':'',
     'B':'234923',
     'C': 'adkasd',
     'D':'kajskdad'}

b = {'A':'',
     'B':'dfdsf',
     'C': 'adkasd',
     'D':''}
```

How to return the `Dict` which has more filed values ( non `''` values) out of these 2 `Dict`s?

I tired this Function:

```
def getLargerData(dict1, dict2):
    countA = len([i for i in dict1.values() if i != ''])
    countB = len([i for i in dict2.values() if i != ''])
    if countA > countB:
        return dict1
    else:
        return dict2
```

Output:

```
{'A':'',
 'B':'234923',
 'C': 'adkasd',
 'D':'kajskdad'}
```

is there any way I can optimize more or alternate solutions for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: actually, I can simply write some for loop for this. but I am expecting a easiest/optimized way to solve this

Comment: What's wrong with a simple loop for this? Share your code 

Comment: sure let me add/paste in the question

Comment: hey, @gvee please let me know, I have updated the answer. I am asking it since the real data will be too large to handle.

Comment: If you're just after the number of values and have a lot of data there is no need to create an array, you could just count and therefore massively decrease the memory requirement. Other than that your solution looks fine to me.

Comment: `sum(1 for i in d.values() if i)` would be one point of optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check for the count of all values in each dictionary.
Thanks to @deceze for the comment to get the oneliner sum of each value of dict.

```
def getLargerData(dict1, dict2):
    countA = sum(1 for i in dict1.values() if i)
    countB = sum(1 for j in dict2.values() if j)
    
    return dict1 if countA > countB else dict2

getLargerData(a,b)
```

Output:

```
{'A': '', 'B': '234923', 'C': 'adkasd', 'D': 'kajskdad'}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, its a bit "optimized"

```
def getLargerData(dict1, dict2):
    '''returns True if dict1 is larger than dict2 otherwise returns false'''
    return len([i for i in dict1.values() if i != '']) > len([i for i in dict2.values() if i != ''])
```

this is how it works:

`def getLargerData(dict1,dict2):` Defines the function

`return` returns IF:

- `len(` the length of

  - `[i for i in dict1.values() if i != '']` returns all the values in dict1 if it isn't none
- `>` returns if that is greater than
- `len(` the length of

  - `[i for i in dict2.values() if i != '']` returns all the values in dict2 if it isn't none

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).